# How can I use partial views in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have done partial views in ASP.NET MVC but now I want to convert it to ASP.NET.  I have used AJAX and JavaScript. How can I convert the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="LoadPartialView('#MainContentDiv', '<%=Url.Action("AdminHome", "Admin")%>')">Home</a>            ,
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="LoadPartialViewPost('#MainContentDiv', '<%=Url.Action("ViewPage", "Controller")%>', $('form').serialize())" />
```

to ASP.NET, or in other words, how can I load a partial view in ASP.NET?

Comment: I think the code you want converted has been somewhat distorted...

Comment: I might be mistaken but I don't think there is any parallel to this in ASP.NET Webforms (I could be mistaken with the new Dynamic Data addition in .NET 4) however you can run MVC inside a web forms application jointly with it.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't partial views in web forms, but you can load user controls through JQuery:

http://samuelmueller.com/2008/12/dynamicloader-plugin-dynamically-loading-asp-net-user-controls-with-jquery/

You can also route in ASP.NET 4: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

HTH.